# Странное количество баллов репутации в уведомлении

Tags: поддержка, репутация, удаление-вопросов, дух-сообщества

Вот такую картину увидел только что:

> [image: +7 в заголовке, но +15 в выпадающем списке]

Иногда и раньше наблюдал тут странные цифры. Это дефект?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На странице [репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q?tab=reputation) вижу такое (вероятно, т.к. модератор).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дух удалил [ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/913037/15479), т.к. у него суммарно `0` голосов. За вопрос кто-то проголосовал "за". Т.е, дали `+10`, кто-то проголосовал против - это `-2`. Суммарно `+8`, после удаления вопроса репутацию отняли. За принятый ответ `+15`.

`15 - 8 = 7`.

Comment: Вот что вижу я: https://i.imgur.com/Ppae7IJ.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ значит только модераторы могут видеть. Упс)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ дух удалил ваш вопрос. Добавил ссылку в ответ.

Comment: Интересно, я только хотел написать что не удалал его =)

Comment: получается это баг

Comment: @StrangerintheQ боюсь, [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано] (:

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Странно это с возвратом репутации. Мне тоже  вчера или позавчера вернулся +1, значит кто-то ответ с моим минусом удалил. Раньше вроде было можно во вкладке "репутация" увидеть - какой вопрос был удалён, теперь никаких следов. Что-то всё таки изменилось?

Comment: @0xdb можно попробовать на MSE спросить.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica А может уже есть вопрос на MSE, новый дизайн уже как пару месяцев, по моему от туда "ноги растут".

Comment: @StrangerintheQ На вкладке "Репутация" снизу есть чекбокс "показать удалённые сообщения". Он у Вас активирован?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Вы оказались правы. теперь все видно

Answer (score 2):

В справке написано, что изменение репутации показывается с момента вашего последнего захода на сайт.

Но там есть некоторое лукавство: если вы получили отрицательное число (допустим минус 2 балла за один downvote), увидели его, а потом получили положительное число -- то при следующем показе будет учтён прошлый минус.

Если зайти через несколько дней, когда уже забыли про прошлый минус то это очень сильно сбивает с толку.

Comment: ошибка в том что я нигде не увидел уведомления об удалении, обычно downvote все-таки отображается красной записью хоть как-то, как и удаление участников, а это действие - нет